# Can a token store funds like an escrow and still meet ERC standards?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, erc-20

In one of my contracts, a user creates an escrow that stores some important information. These escrows are bundled together and passed to another contract, which sends the user tokens. The tokens are actually identical to the escrow in that they store the same information - the one difference is that the tokens do not *store* funds (in ETH) whereas escrow does.

I was thinking, it'd be a lot more efficient if I didn't have to create the same thing twice, but the tokens need to be easily exchangeable, so it's important they meet an ERC standard.

As a small side note, it would be nice if the tokens could meet the ERC20 standard, but because the information they store is unique and very important, it doesn't seem possible. Are there good alternatives or solutions?

Comment: You have standard ERC 721 for non fungible tokens. But they are not compatible with ERC 20.

Comment: Right, so that's a good point, but the question still stands, can you store funds in an ERC721 or an ERC20 (say in a different context).

Comment: There's [ERC-998 Composable Non-Fungible Token Standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/998): _A standard extension for any non-fungible token to own another non-fungible ERC-721 or standard fungible ERC-20 tokens._